# Building 3D Slicer from source: openssl error

Tags: openssl

I am following the [instructions](https://www.slicer.org/wiki/Documentation/Nightly/Developers/Build_Instructions#Qt) to build 3D slicer. I have done it successfully on one system after trying a few different things. I was receiving the below error

symbol SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos, version OPENSSL_1.0.2 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
CMakeFiles/OpenSSL.dir/build.make:114: recipe for target 'OpenSSL-prefix/src/OpenSSL-stamp/OpenSSL-build' failed

I am on another Ubuntu 16.04 system and I am receiving the error. I am not sure how I managed to get it working above and I can't fix it on this system. It seems to be an issue with my openssl installation. I've tried reinstalling all the libraries but no joy

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev libcrypto++-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev --reinstall
```

I've posted it on [3D Slicer forum](https://discourse.slicer.org/t/building-from-source-on-ubuntu-16-04-openssl/1129/2) but not had any success

Comment: Perhaps you have a conflicting version of OpenSSL installed on that system somewhere?

Comment: Ah! The script on that page "get-and-build-openssl-for-slicer.sh" downloads and builds OpenSSL 1.0.1e from source (a frighteningly old, insecure and unsupported version of OpenSSL). OpenSSL 1.0.x built from source does not include versioned symbols. However the Ubuntu supplied OpenSSL has a patch which does include versioned symbols. The error message above mentions a symbol version (OPENSSL_1.0.2) so there is some confusion between the two OpenSSL versions (i.e. the system installed version and the one downloaded and built from source)

Comment: @Matt I'm still confused how I managed to get it working at all on one system. Any suggestions? Should I try to push to upgrade version of openssl used by 3D Slicer?

Comment: Not familiar with 3d slicer only openssl, so I can only help so far. Perhaps your other system does not have the system openssl dev files on it? I would recommend that you go back to the 3d slicer team and get them to use a more up to date version (but that won't help with this problem).